# inserting dates into a table between a start and end date in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I want to create a table with all the dates between a start date and end date. What's the best way to do this without listing every date out in the insert?

for example: start date is 1/1/2018 and end date is 1/4/2018 then the resulting table should be:

```
date
------
1/1/2018
1/2/2018
1/3/2018
1/4/2018
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sequence(date, date)`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) to generate the dates in a range:

```
presto:default> create table dates as
select x from unnest(sequence(date '2018-01-01', date '2018-01-04')) t(x);
...
presto:default> select * from dates;
     x
------------
 2018-01-01
 2018-01-02
 2018-01-03
 2018-01-04
(4 rows)
```

Note: `sequence` works with `date`s since Presto version 0.197.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like:

```
INSERT INTO your_table 
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE date_column BETWEEN DATE '2001-01-01' AND DATE '2018-04-01'
```

Please see the following bits from documentation:

- https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/sql/insert.html
- https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/language/types.html#date-and-time