# Add rows between two dates Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that has 3 columns- start, end and emp_num. I want to generate a new table which has all dates between these dates for every employee. Need to use Presto.

I refered this link - [inserting dates into a table between a start and end date in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021585/inserting-dates-into-a-table-between-a-start-and-end-date-in-presto)

Tried using unnest function by creating sequence but , I don't know how do I create sequence by pulling dates from two columns in another table.

```
select unnest(seq) as t(days)
from (select sequence(start, end, interval '1' day) as seq 
      from table1)
```

Here's table and expected format

```
Table 1:
start       |  end         | emp_num 
2018/01/01  |   2018/01/05 | 1
2019/02/01  |   2019/02/05 | 2


Expected:
start          | emp_num 
2018/01/01     | 1
2018/01/02     | 1
2018/01/03     | 1
2018/01/04     | 1
2018/01/05     | 1
2019/02/01     | 2
2019/01/02     | 2
2019/02/03     | 2
2019/02/04     | 2
2019/02/05     | 2
```

Comment: Create a new table that has all dates. Assuming the table is called "Calendar" and the column is called "mydate" you can then do `SELECT calendar.mydate, emp_num FROM table1 INNER JOIN calendar ON calendar.mydate BETWEEn table1.start and table1.end;`

Comment: @JNevill: I am having hard time in creating the calender table. I have 150+ years in my original data. Can you please tell how do I create this calendar table? I don't know start and end date before hand, those are programatically getting generated and populated into table1

Comment: [Check out this answer which generates sequences of dates on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286153/determining-consecutive-and-independent-pto-days). That was just after a quick search, so I'm betting there are more techniques for prestodb.

Comment: @JNevill: Thanks. I referred to that link earlier but can't seems to get presto equivalents right(especially for the dateadd function) which is why I posted the question. Thanks for reply though

Comment: Gotcha. I wish I had a prestodb box to fart around on to see if I could get you a better answer. Might be worth it just to make a list of dates in excel and import just to get a calendar table set up. They are extremely useful to have in any database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query that might get the job done for your use case.

The logic is to use [Presto `sequence()` function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) to generate a wide date range (since year 2000 to end of 2018, you can adapt that as needed), that can be joined with the table to generate the output.

```
select dt.x, emp_num
from 
    ( select x from unnest(sequence(date '2000-01-01', date '2018-01-31')) t(x) ) dt
    inner join table1 ta on dt.x >= ta.start and dt.x <= ta.end
```

However, as commented JNevill, it would be more efficient to create a calendar table rather than generating it on the fly every time the query runs.

It should be a simple as :

```
create table calendar as
    select x from unnest(sequence(date '1970-01-01', date '2099-01-01')) t(x);
```

And then your query would become :

```
select dt.x, emp_num
from 
    calendar dt
    inner join table1 ta on dt.x >= ta.start and dt.x <= ta.end
```

PS : due to the lack of DB Fiddles for Presto in the wild, I could not test the queries (@PiotrFindeisen - if you happen to read this - a Presto fiddle would be nice to have !).

Comment: I like the idea of a DB fiddle!