# Windows functions orderen by date when some dates doesn't exist

Tags: sql, date, sum, window-functions, presto

Suppose this example query:

```
select
id
, date
, sum(var) over (partition by id order by date rows 30 preceding) as roll_sum
from tab
```

When some dates are not present on date column the window will not consider the unexistent dates. How could i make this windowns aggregation including these unexistent dates?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add rows between two dates Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297340/add-rows-between-two-dates-presto)

Comment: What do you want to do with these dates? If they are null you can use COALESCE to add a date. I sometimes add a dummy date in the far future with COALESCE and then take it out later :-). So do a select first to fix the date and then win the window over that select, in you case replace tab with a select statement containing the COALESCE

Comment: There aren't null dates @MikeAinOz. Unexistent dates are unexistent rows.

Comment: Ok, well, in that case, go with what @Jivan is recommending

Answer (score 2):

You can join a sequence containing all dates from a desired interval.

```sql
select
  *
from (
  select
    d.date,
    q.id,
    q.roll_sum
  from unnest(sequence(date '2000-01-01', date '2030-12-31')) d
  left join ( your_query ) q on q.date = d.date
) v
where v.date > (select min(my_date) from tab2)
  and v.date < (select max(my_date) from tab2)
```

Comment: I had tried it. But my problem is that min and max date to create the interval need to come from other table. When i put something like `select min(date) from tab2` and `select max(date) from tab2` inside sequence, results in an error: `Constant expression cannot contain column reference`

Comment: The sequence effectively has to be input with constant values. To counter that, I would choose a date range which is certain to contain all required dates in all cases, and then filter the list in a wrapper-query. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you would typically use a window range specification, like:

```
select
    id,
    date,
    sum(var) over (
        partition by id 
        order by date 
        range interval '30' day preceding
    ) as roll_sum
from tab
```

However I am unsure that Presto supports this syntax. You can resort a correlated subquery instead:

```
select
    id,
    date,
    (
        select sum(var) 
        from tab t1 
        where 
            t1.id = t.id 
            and t1.date >= t.date - interval '30' day
            and t1.date <= t.date
    ) roll_sum
from tab t
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Presto support window functions with interval ranges.  Alas.  There is an old fashioned way to doing this, by counting "ins" and "outs" of values:

```
with t as (
      select id, date, var, 1 as is_orig
      from t
      union all
      select id, date + interval '30 day', -var, 0
      from t
     )
select id.*
from (select id, date, sum(var) over (partition by id order by date) as running_30,
             sum(is_org) as is_orig
      from t
      group by id, date
     ) id
where is_orig > 0
```